# AAD Authentication Directline & Teams, Disable Security Code

Tags: botframework

I would like to have users authenticated in a v4 bot in both Teams and Directline (rendered on webpage) with as little user interaction as possible.  My code is based on MS BOT Samples Github: BotAuthenticationMSGraph and has not changed at all besides configuration settings.

Right now, the directline pops up an extra tab, if needed presents username/password signin, and always presents six digit code for the user to copy/paste into the chat window.  This completes authentication.

Right now, on teams, the operation is the same aside from a problem where after entering credentials (if needed), the popup then closes before the code can be seen.  However, if I complete the process manually in a browser, pasting the code into teams successfully completes the signin.

How can I disable the need for a six digit code?  Additionally, if anyone knows a fix to prevent the teams signin popup from closing early let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [OAuthCards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/authentication/auth-oauth-card) for authentication in Microsoft Teams.

https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/1001#issuecomment-434530463 is a solution which involves webchat which works with AAD and no magic code.

https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/4632#issuecomment-441957719( refer to @compulim's comment here, who is the developer of Web Chat and has specified the steps to eliminate the magic code flow).

Additionally, [this](https://blog.botframework.com/2018/09/01/using-webchat-with-azure-bot-services-authentication/) explains about the mechanism that’s both more secure and users do not need to deal with any “magic code”.
Also, If your browser is set to block 3rd party cookies, it will again fall back to the magic code flow.

With regards to your last question about the teams signin popup closing early, refer to [this](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-sdk/issues/5482) GitHub issue which deals with a similar issue.

Hope this helps.